# Need to use the model attribute after completion of ajax call in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

In JS file, i am invoking an ajax call on click of button which is in jquery dialog. Spring MVC Controller method is invoked which does db entry & creates an object as per it and add in model. The same object properties i use as arguments for spring:message in dialog, but not able to get the object from model. Is there any other way? **Note:** I need to use message from properties file only.

JSP file

```
 <html>
    ..
    <form:form>
    form elements
    <div id="dialog-form" class="dialogbox">
    <spring:message  code="product.createsuccess" arguments="${message.prodCode}, ${message.customerName}, ${message.warehouseName}, ${message.status}"></spring:message>  
   textbox for entering id & done button code segment
    </div>
    </form:form>
    </html>
```

Properties file

```
product.createsuccess = Product {0} created successfully for Customer {1} at {2} in status {3}.
```

Controller file

```
public @ResponseBody
    String addWarehouseProduct(@PathVariable Long warehouseId, ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
// db operation
model.put("message", createdMessageObjectwithattributes);
return null;
}
```

segment of Javascript file

```
..
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 330,
        width: 540,
        modal: true
    });

    $('#done').click(function(){
            var warehouseId = null;
            // warehouseid got from textbox code
            if(warehouseId != null) {
                var url = $('#contextPath').val() +"/"+ $('#mdmType').val()+ "/addWarehouseProduct/" + warehouseId + "/*.do";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,



                    error: function(e) {

                        alert('Error: ' + e);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is only used when you return a view.

```
public @ResponseBody String
```

means that the method returns a simple String, not a view,  to the client. Note the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

```
return null;
```

means that you in fact return nothing. The client gets an empty response.

```
<spring:message  code="product.createsuccess" arguments="${message...
```

is only evaluated when the page is being rendered. It does not change after the ajax call.

Two easy solutions come to my mind:

- Create the message on the server, return it and insert it into the dialog via JavaScript.
- Create a view (JSP) that contains only the dialog, return that and insert the returned dialog into the current page.

Comment: The 1st option i cannot implement, as message needs to be in props file. Can you explain in detail about implementing 2nd option, I was thinking of reloading only dialog to reflect new model attribute change, but as you told, model can be used only when view is returned.

Comment: You create a jsp that contains only the code for the dialog and return the view just like a normal page.